# Github release vs actual software version

Tags: github

Does anyone know what is the difference between a GitHub release and the actual release that software company announces?

I'm trying to find the different versions of vue.js, on the vue.js official website there are only two versions but on the GitHub repository many releases I was wondered if the two concepts are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release(may be downloadable link) version is just file which is uploaded.

Just they decide to provide only two version(may be latest) on official site.

It is all. If same version, (should be) same file. It is just like top selling tag on a store.

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

When they release a GitHub version, it is supposed to be open source. The one the company releases may have more code they have not reeased yet or is confidential.

Comment: Does it mean that the GitHub version is not the same as the actual version? Because on the GitHub one single software has about 50 releases whereas on the official site it has only a few releases.